# print boolean in Erlang

Tags: io, erlang, format, boolean

I am new to Erlang. I wanted to know how to print boolean in Erlang. I have a function which checks if a number is even or not. It returns a boolean value.

```
io:format("The number is even number?  ~d~n", [is_even(X)] ).
```

the output is 1 or 0 now. How can I display "true" or "false"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Erlang `true` and `false` are atoms. `~d` says "interpret it as integer". I suggest using `~p` instead. This prints most of the things as you would expect and even does pretty printing! You only have to be careful with printing lists of numbers, where all of the numbers are between 32 and 255, because they will be interpreted as strings - use `~w` for them.

Comment: Then, you must be returning 0 or 1 instead of atoms. Can you paste the `is_even` function in your question? Are you sure, you recompiled your file?

Comment: Oh. yes. you are correct. I just realised that it was not returning true but converted to 1 and vice versa.